Perfect forwarding and non-type template parameters
Is "arg" an universal/forwarding-reference or an rvalue-reference?
template<auto&& arg>
struct test {};


Out of pure curiosity, what would be a use-case for this? Seeing HolyBlackCat answer I thought about specializing templates for different global variables (not their value) but, in this case, I can't think about an example where auto&& would make a difference wrt auto&.

I'm not sure yet if there's a use case. But I will write a comment if I finally know. I try to optimize the size of my binary, avoiding copies if possible. I assume there are better ways but I stumbled upon it and was curious.

Compilers diverge on the usage of this thing: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/9edrKzxdb

It is a forwarding (aka universal) reference.
It's easy to check:
// (This needs to be at namespace scope, addresses local variables can't
// be passed to reference or pointer template arguments.).
int x;
test<x> t;

This compiles despite x being an lvalue.

As noted by @user12002570, the standard apparently has a very narrow definition of a "forwarding reference" that only applies to function parameters, which means this technically isn't one (@Brian Bi's answer discusses this in more detail). But I'd argue the choice of words is lowkey defective, this isn't the definition that people usually use.
Usually people say "a forwarding reference" to indicate that a seemingly rvalue reference can become an lvalue reference if given an lvalue, and the answer in this case is yes.

Actually it doesn't compile for me - see demo. Am I missing something ?

@wohlstad Pointer and reference template parameters can only point to global/static variables. When I tested it, I didn't wrap this code in int main() {...}, while you did.

You are right. When I make it global is does compile (demo). +1. You can consider to edit to emphasize this.

Just curious, and how to make an instance of test with r-value template argument?

@Fedor Apparently it's not possible. Interesting! test<std::move(x)> leads to error: non-type template parameter has rvalue reference type.

For non-type template parameters without auto placeholder, rvalue references are prohibited since they are not among allowed structural type.

Aren't placeholder types determined by template argument deduction for some invented function? That would be a forwarding reference in that case. I mean sure, you can say the reference in the invented function is in fact the forwarding reference... but it's a useless distinction, since the invented function is only there to reuse the rules instead of restating them in every scenario.

Forwarding references exist only for the purposes of [temp.deduct.call] and [temp.deduct.type] (will not be discussed here).

A forwarding reference is an rvalue reference to a cv-unqualified template parameter that does not represent a template parameter of a class template (during class template argument deduction ([over.match.class.deduct])).
If P is a forwarding reference and the argument is an lvalue, the type "lvalue reference to A" is used in place of A for type deduction.

In template <auto&& arg> struct test {};, the reference arg is not a forwarding reference. However, when a template argument is supplied for arg, [temp.arg.nontype]/1 tells us to invent a declaration
auto&& x = E;

and the type of arg is the type of x. To find the type of x, we have to use [dcl.type.auto.deduct]/3, which then defers to [temp.deduct.call] with an invented function parameter type U&&. Here, P is U&& and is a forwarding reference. The template parameter U does not represent a template parameter of a class template; instead, U was obtained by "[replacing] [...] auto [...] with a new invented type template parameter", following the wording in [dcl.type.auto.deduct]/3.


Is "arg" an universal/forwarding-reference or an rvalue-reference?

As declared, arg is not a forwarding reference as per temp.deduct.call:

A forwarding reference is an rvalue reference to a cv-unqualified template parameter that does not represent a template parameter of a class template (during class template argument deduction ([over.match.class.deduct])).

Note the emphasis in bold which makes this not a universal/forwarding reference.

Note that cppreference's documentation on forwarding reference contradicts with the c++ standard here. In particular, cppreference page says:

Forwarding references are a special kind of references that preserve the value category of a function argument, making it possible to forward it by means of std::forward. Forwarding references are either:



function parameter of a function template declared as rvalue reference to cv-unqualified type template parameter of that same function template:




auto&& except when deduced from a brace-enclosed initializer list:



auto&& vec = foo();       // foo() may be lvalue or rvalue, vec is a forwarding reference



@HolyBlackCat I've updated the answer which only has cppreference's documentation now.

@rubenvb Yeah, updated the answer with only cppreference quote now.

@HolyBlackCat "Though the conclusion seems to be technically correct " Are you referring to your conclusion(that temp.deduc.call makes it a universal reference or my original post's conclusion that it is not a universal reference). Right now, as per my understanding it is still not a universal reference because here the template parameter is auto&& and cv-unqualified template parameter is also just auto&& and also auto&& is an rvalue reference so "rvalue reference to a cv-unqualified template parameter" doesn't hold which means we don't have a universal reference here.

@HolyBlackCat So basically, I just need to bold the other part of [temp.deduc.call]. Did I miss something here? Or did I misread your first comment. That is, you were also saying that it is not a universal reference and the first part of [temp.deduct.call] should be in bold?

@user12002570 By "the conclusion is correct" I meant your conclusion that this is technically not a forwarding reference (despite it being informally called so). I think this is a lowkey wording defect. "basically, I just need to bold the other part" Yeah, I'd bold the "to a ... template parameter" part.

@HolyBlackCat Updated the answer again. But as you can see in the issue I gave a link to, Jens doesn't seem to agree there is any defect here.

@user12002570 I think he didn't understand what you were saying. To me this is obviously a defective wording (the choice of words has no formal impact here, but is unnecessarily confusing).

@HolyBlackCat Maybe you can comment and explain there the issue. I am not a  native english speaker so I was not able to explain it clearly there most probably. Or maybe this is because of c++ being this complicated.

I'm also not a native speaker, and I don't really want to argue with them as I'm not too familiar with the CWG procedures...

@HolyBlackCat I see, looking at your english use, I assumed you were. Though I was expecting that we should atleast point out the mistake(if not fight/argue) for/against something we think is right/wrong. That is how progress is made. Without argument/discussion/etc it will be like faith/religion. But it's  your choice. Thanks anyways. I'll try some other way to convince them of the defect(if there is any).

@user12002570 If you wish to pursue a specification change, you could try submitting a paper to CWG. I don't think EWG necessarily needs to see it; most people in the room would only be familiar with the behaviour, not the specification. Many specification changes go through the core issues process, but CWG papers may be appropriate in non-defect cases and even some cases of more complex defect resolutions.
